# Materiel ui LinearProgress bar steps

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

how to split a progress bar to more steps to get something like that?
[image]

I try this code but I can't find the option of splitting

```js
<LinearProgress
  variant="determinate"
  classes={{ root: "progressBar", bar: "progressBar-bar" }}
  value={(100 / stepsNumber) * stepNumber}
  valueBuffer={40}
/>
```

Is there some options to add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention **steps**, I would recommend using the [`Stepper`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/) component for this kind of feature.

The following code has a basic version you'll need to get component you're looking for.

```js
// handle the step state
const [stepNumber, setStepNumber] = useState(1);
const stepsNumber = 6;
// create array of steps [0,1,2,...]
const steps = Array.from({ length: stepsNumber }, (_, i) => i);

// ...

<Stepper
  activeStep={stepNumber}
  connector={null}
  style={{
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 300,
  }}
>
  {steps.map((label) => (
    <Step
      key={label}
      style={{
        background: label < stepNumber ? "black" : "grey",
        height: 12,
        flex: 1,
        borderRadius: 12,
      }}
    />
  ))}
</Stepper>
```

I've made a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-linearprogress-forked-hzdq9f?file=/demo.tsx)